# How Could I calculate this quaternion cross product?

Tags: quaternions

Now, I am trying make an idea how can calculate this equation that include quaternion.

$q\otimes \frac{F}{m}\otimes {q}^{*}$

where, $\;q = [ w, x, y, z ];  \;\; {q}^{*} = [ w, -x, -y, -z ];$
$ \frac{F}{m} = [ 0, 0, F/m ];$

when I calculate this equation, 
I am not sure how should I handle $q\otimes \frac{F}{m}$.

Please, let me know.

Comment: either that, or if its a normalized vector then, $m=\sqrt({F_w}^2 + {F_x}^2 + {F_y}^2 + {F_z}^2)$ such that $F/m$. So is it a normalized vector? what is $F$ and $m$ individually; a scalar and/or vector?

Comment: Thanks you for your time. $F$ and $m$ is Thrust and Mass. so it is scalar value. so, We can suppose $\frac{F}{m}$ is kind of constant value.

Comment: I am so sorry, $\frac{F}{m}$ is ${[0, 0, F/m]}^{T}$